# Delete duplicate records and retain latest record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build the query to remove duplicate records and retain the latest in postgres.

Input : Object_Name,Id,name,insert_date,update_date

```
a,NULL,NULL,2023-08-28,
a,NULL,NULL,2023-08-29,
b,test,test1,,2023-08-29
a,NULL,NULL,2023-08-30,
```

Output :Need to delete duplicate rows where object name is same and Id and name is null and need to retain the latest record based on insert date.

```
b,test,test1,,2023-08-29
a,NULL,NULL,2023-08-30
```

I am trying below but it's not working.
Delete from table
where object_name in (select object_name from table except select max(object_name) from table group by object_name)
But it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to fetch every object name with the latest insert date in a subquery or a CTE and then to use `NOT EXISTS` to delete all other rows.

This query will do the first step:

```
SELECT 
  Object_Name, 
  MAX(insert_date) AS insert_date
FROM input
GROUP BY Object_Name;
```

This will be our subquery or CTE. We will keep exactly those rows selected by this query. We will delete all others:

```
WITH maxData AS
  (SELECT 
     Object_Name, 
     MAX(insert_date) AS insert_date
   FROM input
   GROUP BY Object_Name)
DELETE FROM input i
WHERE -- add this if necessary: id IS NULL AND name IS NULL AND
  NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM maxData md WHERE
      i.object_name = md.object_name
      AND i.insert_date = md.insert_date);
```

Note: You wrote this as your requirement:

*Need to delete duplicate rows where object name is same and **Id and name is null** and need to retain the latest record based on insert date*

I don't know if the bold part is just to make clear your desired result after the deletion or if it should actually be a condition.

That's why I wrote the part *add this if necessary:...* in the `WHERE` clause of the above delete command. It's up to you to use that part or not.

Anyway, we can check this is working as expected on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7hVnT9QJ) with your sample data.